# How to store HUGE arrays, for graphs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays

**The data, created in Javascript, with use of jQuery:**

1.) Users answer multiple-choice questions, of which the time it takes to answer (**tX** in ms) is stored, by adding it to an array (**answerTimes**).

2.) Also, it is recorded whether or not the question was answered correctly (**cX** in binary), which is stored into an array as well (**answerCorrects** (I know; it's a shit name. Deal with it)).

e.g.,:

```
var answerTimes = [];
var answerCorrects = [];
// for every answer:
answerTimes[answerTimes.length] = tX
answerCorrects[answerCorrects.length] = cX
// which results in, e.g.:
// answerTimes = [1289, 1784, 1628, 972] and 
// answerCorrects = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0], both of variable length,
// depending on how many questions the user has answered.
// this could well be over a thousand answers!
```

**And here's the thing:**

These are multiple **graphs** (such as, but not limited to these 2) per chapter.
There are also multiple **chapters**, per subject.
There are also multiple **subjects**, per language.
And there are multiple **languages**.

e.g., a user who is learning **Japanese**, and is currently studying his **Kanji**, and is at chapter **4**, wants to review his performance data, presented in the form of graphs.

**The actual question:**

What fashion would be best to work in, in order to store these various arrays in a MySQL database, assuming I'm using AJAX to pass these JS-values on to a PHP that does the MySQL magic?

I'm worried, because if there were to be 1 user, 3 languages, 10 subjects, 7 chapters, and 2 graphs, then there would already be an incredible number of arrays to store.
However these small numbers aren't what I'm aiming for: I want as many users as the market allows me, with as many languages as there are - even ancient ones, no /joke here - and these numbers will continue to expand as time goes by. I want users to be able to learn ANY language possible, and to have as MUCH graphical information about their performance as possible to their disposal.

How the hell am I supposed to store ALL of this data in an organised way, that my script can access these arrays. I know how to work mySQL, but I've never had anything more than some strings and serialised, small arrays to store. Also; how to graph them, I know, it's just the storage part of these huge and many arrays that bothers me.

Hit me!

Comment: you're asking how to do X because that's what you thought of, while describing Y; I wouldn't store this in "an array", I'd use a structured object. I also wouldn't necessarily store this data in a sql database. If you have multiple levels of containment, present the information as fragments, collect your data on a per fragment basis, and store the fragments using a technology that makes the most sense. SQL might be useful, (postgres is safer than mysql, it signals errors on illegal data much better), although I might also recommend a key-value store like redis/mongo

Comment: Do you have something personal against `[].push`?

Comment: I'm sorry mike, but that made no sense to me. I'm a very inexperienced programmer, who's only got PHP, MySQL, JS, HTML and CSS under his belt. And even those aren;t fully mastered yet. How about formulating your summary into a full answer below, with an example/some instructions as well? That would be really helpful and I'd be really grateful ^^.

Answer (score 2):

None of what you are asking - if I am understanding the requirement - is as difficult as you are worried it will be.

Sounds like you might have a structure like:

```
Languages
-------------
  LanguageID
  Name

Subjects
-------------
  SubjectID
  Name

LanguageSubjects
-------------
  LanguageSubjectID
  SubjectID
  LanguageID

Chapters
-------------
  ChapterID
  Name
  LanguageSubjectID

Users
-------------
  UserID

GraphData
-------------
  UserID
  ChapterID
  Scores
```

Comment: This seems correct indeed, but I'm not asking solely about the structure of the information (I'm extremely proficient in logics, so the logical structure isn't what bothers me. Got dat down, bro!). I'm asking about how to store and access them - what (type of) code to use and what type of storage systems.

So: We know the structure of the info. What's next, man? Thanks for your time, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think a NoSQL database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) would be far more suited for that requirement.

Comment: +1 Absolutely, since MongoDB stores documents as JSON objects.

Comment: What makes you think "MongoDB stores documents as JSON objects"? (Actually there's no such thing as a "JSON object". It's either an object or JSON, which is a string.) I'm pretty sure Mongo has its own storage method and it's probably not JSON.

Comment: And NoSQL is probably a bad way to storage statistical data. (There are perfect NoSQL graph databases, but not Mongo.)

Comment: Actually, MongoDB uses BSON, which is their binary-json implementation to store data, you didn't provide an alternative.

Comment: From [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)'s site : **Document-Oriented Storage »
JSON-style documents with dynamic schemas offer simplicity and power.**

Comment: So just because you have no idea about what you're talking about, don't down vote a valid answer.